Launching a interstellar probe using a Operation Plumbbob-like device
Before anyone asks, I am aware of Operation Plumbbob and the urban legend of the manhole cover that went at 6 times escape velocity, but that is besides the point. in this story, humanity detects a signal in 1951 from extraterrestrial origin and tries to send a probe to the target star. however, this is the 1950s, and they do not have that advanced rocketry, so they take a 100 kt nuclear warhead, put it down a 1 km shaft that is around 10 feet wide, and have a probe, around 500 kilos and preferably heat-resistant on the top. would this work, and if so, how fast would the thing go?

You might be better off going with an Orion drive and lots of smaller nukes. My main concern being that even if the probe does reach escape velocity (and I mean solar escape velocity not the Earth's) 1950s electronics is probably not not going to take the acceleration force generated by the bomb very well or for that matter last the thousands of years the journey is still going to take even if it does survive 'blast off'.

so you want to build a probe that can take going through a nuclear explosion, out of vacuume tubes?

Who said anything about vacuum tubes? They'll be lucky to send a steel bottle with a letter inside to the correct hemisphere of the galaxy with that kind of launch!

It's a mother-beautiful interstellar cannon, @elemtilas, and it's gonna be there!

That's pretty much how the French used to shoot rockets to the Moon back in the 19th century, right?

It would burn up long before it reached space. To show this, I will make some assumptions that will seem strange and then will explain why it doesn't matter that they're strange.
With 100%-efficient conversion from nuclear energy into kinetic energy (which, if your space agency is intent on getting a probe out there, we can rely on as applied phlebotinum), we have a final energy and velocity of
$$E=100\,\mathrm{kt}\,\mathrm{TNT}=4.184\times10^{14}\,\mathrm{J}=\frac{1}{2}mv^2=\frac{1}{2}(500\,\mathrm{kg})v^2$$
$$\implies v=\sqrt\frac{2E}{m}=\sqrt{1\,673\,600\,000\,000}\approx1\,293\,677\,\mathrm{m}\,\mathrm{s}^{-1}\approx0.004c.$$
Around 1/300th the speed of light. At that speed relativistic corrections will be negligible but we're still talking about galactic escape velocities. Of course by conservation of energy the probe has will be that of a 100 kiloton nuclear bomb, and it will clear the realistic thermosphere (700 km) in under a millisecond.
If you let the probe fill up the entire circular shaft that's 10 feet (~3 meters) wide as a cylindrical sort of thing, then you can also know the approximate volume of air that it sweeps out as it travels. Approximate the entire atmosphere as a roughly-uniform shell of air covering the Earth ending at the edge of the troposphere (16 km up), and then knowing that the volume of a cylinder is $\pi r^2h$, one finds a volume of approximately 452,389 cubic meters, and at a density of around $1.225\,\mathrm{kg}\,\mathrm{m}^{-3}$, one finds that the approximate mass of air collided with by the probe on the shortest possible way out of the atmosphere will be about 554,176 kilograms. Round up to 555 tons, because that happens to be a fun number (and you will also encounter more air in the upper atmosphere anyway), and then you realize that this probe would, in effect, encounter 555 tons of comparatively-solid stuff moving at 0.4% of lightspeed towards it on its way out of the atmosphere.
We normally think of air as fluid because it mostly is. We also think of water as fluid; water, being incompressible, will actually behave exactly like concrete if you hit it fast enough (Minecraft, among other games, got it wrong). So will air; the limit is the speed of sound, where the air molecules can no longer propagate shockwaves ahead of you and starts behaving markedly different. The speed of sound, $\approx343\,\mathrm{m}\,\mathrm{s}^{-1}$, is a bit slower than your probe will be travelling$^\text{[citation needed]}$, so air will be functionally incompressible from the viewpoint of the probe, and the air, behaving somewhat like concrete, will hit the probe like a 555-ton concrete block moving at a significant fraction of lightspeed.
Needless to say, the probe will not survive that. It would probably be flattened into paper in the first few microseconds of travel and would then disintegrate into a mess of semi-liquid semi-gaseous semi-plasmatic tiny metal shards moving extremely fast through the atmosphere. Sort of like shrapnel from a nuclear explosion (because that's exactly what it is).

Could you reduce the energy-efficiency of the nuclear-to-kinetic conversion to get slower speeds that would help it survive? Sure, but you can't just sink the energy into the void. Wherever that energy goes, it's going into either a) the probe (in the form of heat or kinetic energy, neither of which are good in the quantities a 100-kiloton bomb produces) or b) the surrounding environment. Considering that the probe exists in the surrounding environment, any chunk of the energy going into the surrounding environment means that, even if it's just 1% of that energy, there is still a ton being deposited in the probe, which results in the aforementioned destruction. No matter how you put this, the probe does not survive longer than a millisecond.
You say "a heat-resistant top", but that doesn't really work. At the temperatures of nuclear fire, everything is a gas if it's not heated to ionization and turns into a plasma. We as a species, with 2024-level technology, are not aware of any substance that could withstand the heat from a nuclear blast. Fusion weapons (like megaton-yield nuclear weapons and sometimes smaller and more-modern ones) produce temperatures in the millions of degrees Celsius, while the most temperature-resistant compound known to humanity, hafnium carbonitride (unless a Swiss patent clerk knows something I don't), melts at a mere ~4000 Celsius. Using nuclear bombs for all-at-once propulsion is impossible. Project Orion got around the idea by using very small bombs with a specially-designed system to contain the blast in space where nuclear bombs aren't nearly as dangerous, but this idea is functionally just vaporizing an innocent space probe.

Save me from the desire to be realistic
I love the idea of scientists creating a probe in 1951 and firing it into space using a method similar to Operation Plumbbob. I think it would make a great story.
Unless you expect it to be realistic, meaning true to history...

Radiation damage to the probe would be, in my opinion, catastrophic.
Kinetic damage to the probe would be, in my opinion, catastrophic.
Thermal damage to the probe would be, in my opinion, catastrophic.

And those are just the problems with the launching method.

The bipolar transistor was invented in 1947. While technology appears to advance almost daily today, it most certainly did not in the late 1940s.
The first general purpose computer was created in 1951 (your date of interest). It was called the UNIVAC I. The very first installation (at the U.S. Census Bureau) didn't even ship until 1952. It used 6,000+ vacuum tubes and weighed in excess of 7,500 kg and needed 35 m2 of floor space.

I don't know what you think your probe would be, but Voyager it would not be.
Conclusion
I think you have the beginnings of a cool idea (frankly, a really cool idea), but you need to stop worrying about whether or not launching something into space via Operation Plumbbob is possible and spend some time researching what 1951 technology really was, because I think there's a solution for you there, but the word "probe" won't be involved.
Unless you flip the proverbial bird at "realistic" and simply write a good story. How you launch the probe is, after all, just window dressing for the story.
